# Senatorial Class I, II, III races; Special Elections; & Georgia

Tags: united-states, election, senate

2020 was an unusual year for Georgia elections because they voted on *both* of their Senate seats after Senator Johnny Isakson's resignation in 2019 triggered an off-year special election between his appointed successor Kelly Loeffler and Raphael Warnock.

Since Isakson was a Class III Senator, and Warnock won the election, does he inherit this position and will need to be re-elected in 2022? If I understand correctly, 2020 was a Class I election, thus Ossoff is good til 2026?

Comment: What do you mean "Constitutionally required to be held separately"?

Comment: Article 1, Section 3 of the [U.S. Constitution](https://www.senate.gov/civics/constitution_item/constitution.htm#a1_sec3) 

> Immediately after they shall be assembled in Consequence of the first Election, they shall be divided as equally as may be into three Classes. The Seats of the Senators of the first Class shall be vacated at the Expiration of the second Year, of the second Class at the Expiration of the fourth Year, and of the third Class at the Expiration of the sixth Year, so that one third may be chosen every second Year

Comment: What part of that is unusual to Georgia?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- none of it is unique to Georgia, but Georgia is unique in that it is the only state that is electing two senators at once in the elections for the 117th congress.  Electing two senators at once is somewhat unusual, but It has happened before, for example when Kirsten Gillibrand and Chuck Schumer both won reelection in New York in 2010.

Comment: @phoog Then I'm not sure what the first sentence means

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- unusual (not unique) in that it doesn't happen often? Perhaps I should have used uncommon instead? According to centerforpolitics.org, the last four double-barrel elections was 2014, 2010, 2008 and 1996. I'd say there's enough election cycles between this group to warrant an "uncommon" then?

Comment: Check that edit @jbro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Warnock is elected in a **special election** (Class III) to fill the vacancy caused by the resignation of Senator [Johnny Isakson](https://bioguideretro.congress.gov/Home/MemberDetails?memIndex=i000055). Warnock will serve for the remainder of Senator Isakson's term which ends on January 3, 2023. This explains why he will be up for re-election in 2022.

Ossoff is elected in a **scheduled election** (Class II) so his 6-year term will end on January 3, 2027. He will thus be up for re-election in 2026. *(Note that this seat is a Class II seat, not I as mentioned in your question. All [2020 scheduled Senate elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_Senate_elections) were Class II seats.)*